# How to render jade layout with loop of users

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to render something like it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class"test">
       User 1
    </div>
    <div class"test">
       User 2
    </div>
    <div class"test">
       User 3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class"test">
       User 4
    </div>
    <div class"test">
       User 5
    </div>
    <div class"test">
       User 6
    </div>
</div>
```

I need 3 .test for each .row:

```
  - var count = 0
  div.row
  for user in Users
    - count++
    -if ((count % 3) == 0)
      div.test  
        | #{user.name}
      div.row
    -else
      div.test
        | #{user.name}
```

But, it does not working because when the loop try to render "div.row" its automatically close the tag.

The wrong result is:

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="test">User 1</div>
<div class="test">User 2</div>
<div class="test">User 3</div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="test">User 4</div>
<div class="test">User 5</div>
<div class="test">User 6</div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible ways is to reorganize your Users array before you send it to jade.

```
Users = [[user1,user2,user3],[user4,user5,user6],...
```

And then in jade

```
for group in Users
    div.row
        for user in group
            div.test
                | #{user.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = [{'1':'a','t':0},{'2':'b','t':0},{'3':'c','t':0},{'4':'d','t':0},{'5':'e','t':0},{'6':'f','t':0},{'8':'h','t':0},{'9':'i','t':0}];
//console.log(test)
var i=1;
var j=1;
_.each(test,function(t){
    t.g = j;
    if((i % 3) == 0){
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    return(t);
});
var test2 = _.groupBy(test,function(t){return t.g});
console.log(test2);
```

[image: Answer]